# How to find parameters (variables) in a web site by using google chrome for JMeter

Tags: google-chrome, jmeter, jmeter-5.0, google-developers-console

I just started to use JMeter. I want to know how can I see the variables at google chrome. I tried so many ways and I watched lots of videos but there are no answers. Every video says that; you can find it in the network page from console.  But on the website which im looking for variables, I just can see JavaScript code token. There is no token as variable. Is there a way to import it into JMeter or is there other way to find variables in google chrome. To put it in a nutshell, I'm working on a project. I want to load test for a website but I got problems with POST request. I cannot login the threads because of cannot find the variables. I need help !! :(
[This is what I am trying to reach with screenShot...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjbBr.jpg)
[This is my chrome's screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcWem.jpg)
I'm just tryna get the parameters like first pic.

Comment: Could you please add some screenshot, what you have tried so far? because it is very difficult to answer only on the statement without any reference. There are lot of tools you can use if you don't find it in the network tab, like httpwatch or fiddler. But can't suggest unless until you put some reference.

Comment: I just edited my post. I want to get parameters like in the first pic. But web site which I'm working on, there is just JSON format. I can't understand what I'm going to do for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities:

1. The "variable" comes in the response, take a closer look at:

   - response URL as it may be a part of the URL after [redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)
   - [response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header) (can be observed in the ["Network" tab](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) of the developer tools)
   - response body, you can view [page source](https://www.howtogeek.com/416108/how-to-view-the-html-source-in-google-chrome/)
2. The variable gets "calculated" in the browser using JavaScript code. If this is the case you should [find the relevant JavaScript function](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/) and implement it using JMeter's [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

You can also try recording your test scenario using BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder, it's capable of exporting recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of the dynamic parameters. In case #2 it will not help, but if the variable comes with the response most probably it will be able to detect it. More information: [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80)

Comment: I cannot find the solution of my problem but I learned lots of things cause of your help. Thanks a lot :)